# When do I need to specify explicit lifetimes in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime-scoping

If I have the two functions

```
// implicit
fn foo(x: &i32) {
}

// explicit
fn bar<'a>(x: &'a i32) {
}
```

When would `foo` return an error and `bar` be the correct function header? I'm confused as to **why** I would explicitly declare a lifetime:

> The 'a reads ‘the lifetime a’. Technically, every reference has some
>   lifetime associated with it, but the compiler lets you elide them in
>   common cases.

I understand what a lifetime is, but what does explicitly specifying a lifetime `'a` **do** for me? For reference I'm using the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html) as reading material

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Practically speaking, the #1 reason you'll have to write lifetime annotations is *because the compiler asks you so*. It will reject function signatures which are not covered by [lifetime elision rules](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/704f0060176418659698eb63642e2071b109e029/active/0000-lifetime-elision.md).

I assume you would like an simple example where lifetimes are mandatory. Imagine the following scenario:

```
struct Blah<'a> {
    hoy: &'a u8
}

fn want_a_hoy(blah: &Blah) -> &u8 {
    blah.hoy
}
```

The intention is obvious, but the compiler doesn't handle it:

```
<anon>:7:35: 7:38 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
<anon>:7     fn want_a_hoy(blah: &Blah) -> &u8 {
                                           ^~~
<anon>:7:35: 7:38 help: see the detailed explanation for E0106
<anon>:7:35: 7:38 help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but 
                        the signature does not say which one of `blah`'s 2 elided 
                        lifetimes it is borrowed from
```

In this case, annotations solve the problem:

```
fn want_a_hoy<'a, 'b>(blah: &'b Blah<'a>) -> &'a u8 {
    blah.hoy
}
```

Here you're specifying `'a` twice (on `Blah<'a>` and `&'a`). This is the same lifetime! So what you're saying to the compiler here is: "This function takes a reference to a blah containing an inner reference. I will return something which lives exactly as long as the inner reference of the blah." In this case, the signature gives a strong hint that you're likely to return something coming from the innards of the blah.

Comment: An even simpler example where lifetime elision fails is `fn pick_one(a: &T, b: &T) -> &T` (even if it always returns one of them unconditionally).