# Does the third rule of lifetime elision capture all cases for struct implementations?

Tags: rust, lifetime

The third rule of lifetime elision says

> If there are multiple input lifetime parameters, but one of them is `&self` or `&mut self` because this is a method, then the lifetime of `self` is assigned to all output lifetime parameters. This makes writing methods much nicer.

Here is the [tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) describing what happened for this function

```
fn announce_and_return_part(&self, announcement: &str) -> &str
```

> There are two input lifetimes, so Rust applies the first lifetime elision rule and gives both `&self` and `announcement` their own lifetimes. Then, because one of the parameters is `&self`, the return type gets the lifetime of `&self`, and all lifetimes have been accounted for.

We can show that all the lifetimes are not accounted for since it is possible that `announcement` will have a different lifetime than `&self`:

```
struct ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    fn announce_and_return_part(&self, announcement: &str) -> &str {
        println!("Attention please: {}", announcement);
        announcement
    }
}

fn main() {
    let i = ImportantExcerpt { part: "IAOJSDI" };
    let test_string_lifetime;

    {
        let a = String::from("xyz");
        test_string_lifetime = i.announce_and_return_part(a.as_str());
    }
    println!("{:?}", test_string_lifetime);   
}
```

The lifetime of `announcement` is not as long as `&self`, so it is not correct to associate the output lifetime to `&self`, shouldn't the output lifetime be associated to the longer of the input?

Why is the third rule of lifetime elision a valid way to assign output lifetime?

Comment: I totally thought the same thing as you when I read that.  I guess the important thing to know along with the response below is that the code you posted fails to compile, complaining of a `lifetime mismatch` between the `announcement` argument and the return type in the function prototype, explicitly noticing that you're returning data from `announcement`.

Thanks for posting this.

Comment: By the way, for future Googlers: If you add an explicit (and matching) lifetime to `announcement` and the return type in the prototype, the function compiles, but then rust (correctly) complains about the lifetime not being long enough in `main()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the elision rules do *not* capture every possible case for lifetimes. If they did, then there wouldn't be any elision rules, they would be the **only** rules and we wouldn't need any syntax to specify explicit lifetimes.

Quoting from the documentation you linked to, emphasis mine:

> The patterns programmed into Rust's analysis of references are called
>   the lifetime elision rules. These aren't rules for programmers to
>   follow; the rules are a set of **particular cases that the compiler will
>   consider, and if your code fits these cases, you don't need to write
>   the lifetimes explicitly**.
>
> The elision rules don't provide full inference: if Rust
>   deterministically applies the rules but **there's still ambiguity as to
>   what lifetimes the references have, it won't guess what the lifetime
>   of the remaining references should be**. In this case, the compiler will
>   give you an error that can be resolved by adding the lifetime
>   annotations that correspond to your intentions for how the references
>   relate to each other.

---

> The lifetime of `announcement` is not as long as `&self`, so it is not correct to associate the output lifetime to `&self`
>
> Why is the third rule of lifetime elision a valid way to assign output lifetime?

"correct" is probably not the right word to use here. What the elision rules have done is **a** valid way, it just doesn't happen to be what you might have wanted.

> shouldn't the output lifetime be associated to the longer of the input?

Yes, that would be acceptable for this example, it's just not the most common case, so it's not what the elision rules were aimed to do.

See also:

- [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609137/155423)
- [When do I need to specify explicit lifetimes in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31083746/155423)
- [When is it useful to define multiple lifetimes in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29861388/155423)
- [Why would you ever use the same lifetimes for references in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44709632/155423)

Comment: but in the doc it says `Then, because one of the parameters is &self, the return type gets the lifetime of &self, and all lifetimes have been accounted for.` , but it seems like all the lifetime has not been accounted for, how does the compiler know that assigning `&self` lifetime is the valid one?

Comment: @Jal yes, all the arguments / return types that require lifetimes have been *assigned* lifetimes, but that doesn't mean that the compiler-assigned lifetimes are the most precise or what you need. Perhaps the issue is just centered on the semantics around the phrase "accounted for"?

Comment: ah, I see, the compiler just assign the lifetime to the most general case, which maybe a case that is not correct.

Comment: @Jal: I'd like to add that the compiler shouldn't have to look at the implementation of a function. Lifetime elision rules are only concerned about the function signature. If it matches a certain pattern, lifetimes are assigned automatically. `fn(&self, &str) -> &str` is *always* short for `fn<'a>(&'a self, &str) -> &'a str` regardless of how you implement that function. In your case, this matching pattern is not what you want which is why you have to be specific about the lifetimes.

Comment: `it won't guess what the lifetime of the remaining references should be`. Certainly seems like the compiler is guessing here. When I read that part of the book - even those exact quotes - I thought the same thing: the compiler only uses elision rules in common cases, where there is only one possible way to set explicit lifetimes anyway. Apparently not. The book could use some better wording to clarify this.